# Wired RF connection without antenna

Tags: diy, coaxial-cable, ht

I’d like to build a radio system for use in underground caves. Wireless signals are nearly impossible to propagate in this environment, so I’d like to run long coaxial cable between each station. Are there any resources to read about this kind of system?
As the most basic setup, I think I can just remove the antennas from 2 handheld radios and connect them with a long coax cable. I’m looking for help calculating the maximum cable length and power requirements (attenuation required?), and how that changes when multiple transceivers are added to the system.

Comment: if you’re going to connect them directly using some kind of cable or wire, I’m pretty sure you’ve just described a telephone system not a radio system. make life easy on yourself and get some old POTS handsets that can run off line voltage. then declare victory!

Answer (score 3):

> I think I can just remove the antennas from 2 handheld radios and connect them with a long coax cable.

No, you cannot.

Don't do that!

If you do that, you will most certainly destroy  the receiving circuit in the hand helds.

Comment: Well, 1000' of thin coax at UHF *might* be enough of an attenuator, depending :)

Answer (score 3):

You typically avoid coax for stiffness, volume and robustness reasons. For the negligibly low bandwidths you need, baseband communication over copper wire simply works - as in every field telephone since the first world war.

No need, nor advantage at all, to go RF.

If you need multiple channels, go digital and use one of many many standards. Sounds a bit like ISDN to me, but much simpler systems would also do even if you needed massive amounts of channels.

Comment: Field telephone would work fine in this application but they are hard to find. The reason I thought of RF is that handheld ham radios are cheap and readily available, so easy to replace if it breaks.

Comment: Field telephones are rather trivial to find: any analog landline telephone of the last 11 decades would work in a pinch without access to military surplus

Answer (score 3):

as Mike Waters said, connecting the RF form one radio to another will damage the receiving circuits. Normally received RF is very low power and all radios have amplifiers to increase the signal level so it can be decoded. At a minimum you would need antennation in the coax cable to reduce the power level to something the receiver can handle. This would be similar to the RF attenuators some hams use so they can view their RF output on an oscilloscope.

As Marcus said since you are directly connecting the two devices there is no need to cover the audio to RF and to have to convert it bac to audio, just send the audio frequency over the connection. In short you need a telephone, not a radio.

You could route coax cables from under ground to the surface and put an antenna on the surface.

Depending on the distance a long run of coax might might provide enough attenuation, but this would need to be carefully checked before connecting your radio. If sending audio, essentially a telephone, you might even need an audio amplifier.

For shorter distances, you might even be able use sound powered equipment. The military uses them in some cases. The microphone actually use the energy from your voice to generate voltage instead of just modulating an existing voltage.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound-powered_telephone

Answer (score 1):

Directly connecting radios together is a non-starter, and if that's what you're doing, analogue (POTS) telephones would be a better design, with something (battery? generator?) providing line voltage to get you a party line.

If using radios appeals still, though, you could look into ["leaky feeders"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_feeder) - these are designed for underground tunnels where propagation isn't great, and instead have the coax act as the antenna in a controlled fashion. You'd then use your handhelds as-if you were at the surface, but the signal path is mostly contained in your coax, rather than propagating through air.